# Revert gcd command in git

Tags: git

I had lots of uncommitted changes in my project using git.
I was trying to use `cd ..`, but instead typed `gcd ..` and pressed enter key.
Which stated this message,
`Updated 38 paths from 4c2285f`

How do I bring back those changes?
Help!

Comment: What is `gcd`? Is it an alias you have for a specific command?

Comment: Based on the output message, I wonder if `gcd` is an alias for `git checkout`? Let's hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65943989/184546) isn't what happened to you.

Comment: Side note that likely won't help you right now, but maybe it will for the future. I think your first sentence might better be written as "I had lots of uncommitted changes in my project *that hasn't used Git in a while*." In order to *use* Git, you need to make commits, preferably early and often so you don't lose any work. Note in Git you can always re-work your commits later to make them look like your final desired goal, but until you commit, you aren't really saving your work. (Caveat, if you ever staged your files, you may be able to still find them, even though you never committed them.)

Comment: This question cannot be answered without additional detail, since `gcd` isn't a standard command in the `git` suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check gcd alias with this command

```
alias gcd
```

[image]

In my case, `gcd` stands for `git checkout $(git_develop_branch)` If you find yourself in a similar situation, you can simply return to your previous branch. For instance, if you were on the branch called `my_previous_branch`, you can type `git checkout my_previous_branch` to switch back to it. If you have committed your changes, you can check your `git log` and reset to the commit head. Alternatively, you can use `git reflog` to find the commit ID and then reset it to that specific commit's head.

Comment: Good guess, but my crystal balls says that OP's gcd has something to do with the Greatest Common Delta. :)

Comment: Haha, nice try! But according to my mystical sources, it seems that the OP's "gcd" actually stands for the Groundbreaking Cheese Dip. Clearly, we're dealing with a deliciously cheesy situation here, rather than any mathematical mysteries! :)